# HQL delete not working in a java servlet

Tags: java

I am battling with an HQL delete query.I have a custom jsp that displays some records from the database according to certain criteria. My attempt is to mark a certain number of  rows displayed in a custom jsp from the database. I can  mark the records and correctly read their row id's (I have tested that). So I am attempting to delete the marked rows using HQL in custom servlet but the records are not deleted I am not sure if there is a need for extra configuration on the persistence file.
Any contribution about HQL DELETE or UPDATE in a servlet is welcome my code for the servlet is as below

```
package net.billing.deleterecords;

import java.io.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import org.openxava.jpa.*;

@WebServlet("/deleteDiaryServlet")
public class deleteDiaryServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{

        String[] marked_records = request.getParameterValues("marked_record");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("The deleted records are: ");
        out.print("<ul>");
        for(String selected:marked_records){
            out.print("<li>" + selected + "</li>");
                out.print("<li>" + selected+  "</li>");
            String oid = "8a4b301f5b142791015b142c13c50002";
            Query query = XPersistence.getManager()
                        .createQuery("delete from Diary diary where diary.oid=:oid");
               query.setParameter("oid",oid);
               int count= query.executeUpdate();
               System.out.println("Rpws affected"+count);
        }

        out.print("</ul>");
        out.print("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

Comment: You are working with a fix oid! `String oid = "8a4b301f5b142791015b142c13c50002";`

Comment: You should learn about Software architecture. Do not use the persistence layer directly in the view

Comment: Thanks Jens for advise I have just included String oid = "8a4b301f5b142791015b142c13c50002";  for the case of testing only if the delete would work.I am getting the value from another jsp to the servlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to commit your transaction. Try adding

```
XPersistence.commit()
```

after your for loop, so that all delete transactions will get committed together.

Comment: Thanks a lot I XPersistence.commit() solved my problem Thank you so much

Comment: glad it helped, just mark your question as answered then... :)

Comment: Let me do like wise